# minimum changes to N lines to make a given line a subsegment of all of them

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

there's a line segment `LS`  of length `l` and `N` other line segments whose end points are given like, `(a1, b1), (a2,b2), ... (an, bn)` [both the points inclusive]. All the values in the ranges are less than or equal to a given value `k`. find the minimum units of changes you need to make in those `N` line segments to make `LS` a subsegment with all the `N` line segments. (Assume all the line segments are horizontal) e.g.,

```
N=4
l=2
k=8
ranges: (1,2), (2, 5) (1,8), (2,4)

1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
---
    -----
---------------
  -----

ans: 2 (increase 1st line by 1 unit towards 3 and second line by 1 towards 2) or
(increase line 1 by 2 units upto 4)
```

right now what I am doing is that I am creating an array of size `k` initialized by 0 and incrementing the values of ranges by 1 and then finally finding the window of size `l` with maximum sum and subtracting that sum from `n*l`. But, the problem is when all the `N` line segments are of full length i.e. `(1, k)`. Then the update time becomes `O(N*k)` or `O(N^2)` if `N=k`. Is there a ay to do it in less than `O(N*k)`?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which is LS in your example?

Comment: @cobarzan : LS is not shown as it does not have a range it just has a length. the answer in the above example is 2 (explaination provided) in that case the range of `LS` would be `(2,3)`. But that is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an O(N log N + k) approach.

First, create lists of all the start and end points of the segments.  Sort each list.

Imagine a vertical line sweeping right to left, whose position is given by `i`.  Maintain a value `s[i]` which is the number of segments whose right endpoints are greater than `i`.  Since you have a sorted list of right endpoints, `s[1:k]` can be computed in O(N+k) time.  Using this, you can populate an array `L[i]` whose values are the number of units of units of leftward movement to have all segments start at position `i` or lower.  `L[k+1] = 0` and `L[i] = L[i+1] + s[i]`.

You can do a similar thing from left to right to compute `R[j]`, the number of units of rightward movement to have all segments end at position `j` or higher

Now the total units of movement to have all line segments overlap the interval from `i` to `j` is `R[i] + L[j]`.

The total time for this approach is O(N log N) to sort the endpoints, plus O(N+k) for the rest of the algorithm, for a total bound of O(N log N + k).

With a little fussing around, you could probably improve this to O(N log N) by only computing `R[i]` and `L[j]` near the interval endpoints.